# How to add a Skills section in latex Expressive Resume

Tags: cv

I just want to add a skills section in my resume in latex [Expressive Resume](https://github.com/thehale/expressive-resume)
Like this one [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Next time you ask a question please show us what you already tried, in this case you could have tried to use `itemize` or similar. At least we can then copy your labels and text.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % set margins of document; not necessary
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor} % just for demo; not necessary

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{description}
            \item[Languages:] C, Python, Matlab, TCL scripting
            \item[Logic Synthesis:] DC(synopsys), Genus(Cadence)
            \item[Signoff tools:] StarRC, PrimeTime, Calibre, Virtuoso
            \item[Physical Verification:] LVS, DRC, ERC, Density rules
            \item[HDL:] Verilog, VHDL
            \item[Place \& Route:] ICC(Synopsys), Innovus(Cadence)
            \item[FE Tools:] Vivado, VCS, QuestaSim, HSpice
            \item[Technologies:] Linux, GitHub, Git, \LaTeX\textcolor{red}{, some more to show you how a linebreak looks like and how the spacing is adapted such that both columns have the same height}
        \end{description}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]